# If $|a-b| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a| \gt \epsilon$, constructively prove that $|b|\geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have a proof for the claim, but it's ugly and involves cases and a contradiction. Is there a **constructive proof** for the statement:

> If $|a-b| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a| \gt \epsilon$, then $|b|\geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

I'm guessing it involves the triangle inequality theorem, but I am struggling to pin it down.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$|a-b|\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}\Leftrightarrow -\frac{\epsilon}{2}\le a-b\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}\Leftrightarrow a-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\le b \le a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\qquad (1)$$

$$|a|>\epsilon \Leftrightarrow a
<-\epsilon \text{ or } a>\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \left(a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}
<-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \text{ or } \left(a-\frac{\epsilon}{2}>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)\qquad(2)$$

Now, put both inequalities, $(1)$ and $(2)$, together. Can you finish?

Comment: Oh! That's a great way of breaking it in to cases. I'll remember that. Cheers~

Answer (score 3):

Using
$$ |x-y|\ge|x|-|y| $$
one has
$$ |b|=|a-(a-b)|\ge|a|-|a-b|>\epsilon-\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}. $$

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the inverse triangle inequality, that is for any real numbers $a$ and $b$ we have
$$|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|.$$

On the one hand,
$$|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Hence,
$$|a|\leq |b|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$

Also $|a|>\varepsilon$, so
$$\varepsilon<|a|\leq |b|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
In particular,
$$\varepsilon<|b|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
where the inequality is strict because of the fact that $\varepsilon<|a|$, and the result is proven:
$$|b|>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$